# Java exercise - display table with 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling to finish a java exercise, it involves using 2d arrays to dynamically create and display a table based on a command line parameter.

Example:

java table 5

```
+-+-+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|4|5|
+-+-+-+-+-+
|2|3|4|5|1|
+-+-+-+-+-+
|3|4|5|1|2|
+-+-+-+-+-+
|4|5|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+-+-+
|5|1|2|3|4|
+-+-+-+-+-+
```

What i have done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    String[][] table = new String[num*2+1][num];

    int[] numbers = new int[num];
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        numbers[i] = i+1;

        // wrong
    for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<num;j++){
            if(i%2!=0){
            temp=numbers[0];
            for(int k=1; k<numbers.length; k++){
                numbers[k-1]=numbers[k];
            }
            numbers[numbers.length-1]=temp;
            for(int l=0; l<numbers.length; l++){
            table[i][j] = "|"+numbers[l];
            }
            }
            else
                table[i][j] = "+-";
    }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<table.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<num; j++)
        System.out.print(table[i][j]);
        if(i%2==0)
            System.out.print("+");
        else
            System.out.print("|");

        System.out.println();}
}
```

This doesn't work, since it prints 1|2|3|4 in every row, which isn't what I need. I found the issue, and it's because the first for loop changes the array order more times than needed and basically it returns as it was at the beginning.

I know that probably there's a way to achieve this by writing more code, but I always tend to nest as much as possible to "optimize" the code while I write it, so that's why I tried solving this exercise by using less variables and loops as possible.

Comment: If you found the printing issue, what *do* you need help with?

Comment: I need help finding a way to solve the issue, since i spent half day trying but couldn't find any :\

Comment: you want to just print the table with int[][] as input data or you need to save exactly the table format as string[][]? e.g. it would be String[11][11] for each line and column. many lines would be duplicated though. (those +-+-+...)?

Comment: To me, it seems that, in order to accomplish this, you need to pre-define the data length max of each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too complex. Hard to find your error. Straight code follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    //int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int num = 5; // for test

    // creating 2d array
    int[][] figures = new int[num][num];

    // filling the array
    for(int row=0; row<figures.length; ++row) {
        for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {
            figures[row][col] = (row + col) % num + 1; 
        }
    }

    // printing the array
    for(int row=0; row<figures.length; ++row) {

        // printing border
        for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {
            System.out.print("+-");
        }
        System.out.println("+");

        // printing data row
        System.out.print("|");
        for(int col=0; col<figures[row].length; ++col) {
            System.out.print(figures[row][col]);
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // printing final border
    for(int col=0; col<figures[0].length; ++col) {
        System.out.print("+-");
    }
    System.out.println("+");


}
```

Comment: Thanks so much mate, i guess i'll have to stop thinking too hard and try different approaches rather than focusing on just one ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
int dimension = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
int[][] twoDimArray = new int[dimension][dimension];
for(int i=0;i<dimension;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<dimension;j++){
    System.out.print("|"+((i+1)%(dimension+1)));
    }  //end of j loop
 } //end of i loop
} //end of main
```

The above is only the logic for printing the numbers in the specified sequence.
The other design pattern ( +-+ ) thing i guess u can manage.

Comment: Gee, you solved with so little lines.. I kinda feel stupid now :)

Answer (score 1):

the following codes will initialize a 2d int array for the data (1-5 in your example). and print the table. note that the table structure was not save in a String 2d-array. just print the table out.  see comments in line.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        final int num = 5; //hardcoded 5, just for testing.
        final int[][] data = new int[num][num];
        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < data[r].length; c++) {
                final int t = r + c + 1;
                data[r][c] = t <= num ? t : t - num;
            }
        }
        // now we have all int data in data 2D-array    
        // here is the +-+- line
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("+");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            sb.append("-+");    
        // now print the table
        for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            for (int c = 0; c < data.length; c++) 
                System.out.print("|" + data[r][c]);
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }
```

output:

if you give num=9 as argument. the codes above will print:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|1|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|1|2|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|4|5|6|7|8|9|1|2|3|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|5|6|7|8|9|1|2|3|4|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|6|7|8|9|1|2|3|4|5|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|7|8|9|1|2|3|4|5|6|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|8|9|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|9|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: Thank you too for this additional example ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have make it more complicated try this Simple code  :

```
enter code here
 public static void main(String[] args)    
{
  int n  =   5 ;
  for(int i = 1 ; i <= n  ;i++)
  {
      for(int l = 0  ; l < n;l++)
       System.out.print("+-");

      System.out.print("\n|");
      for(int j = i ; j <=n;j++ )
      {
          System.out.print(j+"|");

      }
     for(int k = 1 ; i >= 2 && k <=i-1;k++)
     {
         System.out.print(k+"|");
     }
      System.out.println();
  }
```

}